# I've created the simplest project from the new project wizard. It compiles just fine but fails to deploy. How can I find why?

Tags: xamarin.android

An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
The system cannot find the file specified

```
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Need more log or info

Comment: Probably it's broken.

Comment: thanks buddy, but how can I fix that?

Comment: Please post a [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output).

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information.
What kind of project did you create?

Switch the all the log verbosities to diagnostic and post the log here:

Tools/Options/Xamarin/Android Settings/Xamarin Diagnostic Output verbosity => switch to Diagnostics

Tools/Options/Projects and solutions/Build and Run/MsBuild project build / log file output => switch both to Diagnostics